# How can I have a master detail flow with each uiviewcontroller layered on top of the previous

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a new universal iOS app that I'd like to use the following interaction pattern (when in a non-iPhone size class):

Starting with a full-screen tableview, the user can navigate through successive viewcontrollers, with each new one effectively "stacked" or layered over the previous one, with the previous one fixed to the left edge of the screen and the current one occupying around 80% of the screen's width, so the previous one can be seen "underneath". To go back, the user taps anywhere on the previous (greyed out) view.

[image: interaction flow]

I thought this might be possible with the default master-view template but that almost seems to do the reverse of what I'm after. I also looked at some third-party cocoapods, such as `PKRevealController` and `ECSlidingViewController` but they don't appear to be maintained any more.

Is this type of interaction possible and straightforward? What sort of approach should I take?

Comment: it doesn't seem user friendly at least on the phone ?

Comment: If the two third party you mentioned are not keep maintained, but do the job, why don't you use them or copy their implementation? I don't know how it's viable, but a custom segue do that job?

Comment: @Shubhank I should have said that this would only apply to iPad-esque size classes. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like Spotify solved the problem for me. [SPStackedNav](https://github.com/spotify/SPStackedNav) has an SPStackedNavigationController which does exactly what I want to do.

Comment: :D, always nice when you find a 3rd party control or library which does what you want